# Pjax not working, reload the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, gridview, yii2, pjax

I'm developing a project using Yii2 and get frustrated with Pjax because it never works for me. Here is a simple gridview with pjax that I have created:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'member-list-pjax', 'timeout' => 5000]);?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'member_card_number',
            'member_name',
            [
                'attribute' => 'member_address',
                'format' => 'raw',
            ],
            'member_phone1',
            'member_phone2',
            [
                'attribute' => 'member_type',
                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column){
                    return $model->getTypeLabel($model->member_type);
                },
                'filter' => $searchModel->getTypeLabel(),
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end();?>
```

The Pjax doesn't work at all. When I search something in gridview's filter, it reloads the entire page. There is also no javascript error. Can anybody help me?

**UPDATE**

My action is actually very long. But here is the part that I think is related to the gridview:

```
$searchModel = new MemberSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

if (isset($_GET['MemberSearch']))
    $searchModel->attributes = $_GET['MemberSearch'];

return $this->render('form', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I use kartik's gridview now, I removed the PJax and put 'pjax' => true in the gridview, it successfully do Ajax Filter, BUT still reload the whole page not long after.

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pjax' => true,
    'pjaxSettings' => [
        'neverTimeout' => true,
    ],
    'columns' => [ /*columns same as above*/ ]
]);
```

Comment: check your ajax response, pjax will load entire page if there is html present in reponse

Comment: Check id, maybe is duplicate. Also you can check this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/65794-pjax-reload-gridview-should-stay-on-same-page/)

Comment: try set higher timeout (10000) for testing purposes (page is reloaded if result is not returned with 200 OK within your timeout).
in which way is your action code different from the generated one?

Comment: @NitinP Why does it return html in response?

Comment: @tigrasti no id is duplicated

Comment: @e-frank I set it to 10000 but still no luck

Comment: can you post your action?

Comment: @e-frank I have updated this post with my action

Comment: see example here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/

avoid nested pjax for simplicity.
check pjax linkSelector

Answer (score 1):

Please check your id and put this javascript in top of the page

```
$('body').on('click','.reload',function(){
    $.pjax.reload({container: '#w0-pjax'});
});
```

Also use below code

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['linkSelector'=>'','id'=>'w0-pjax']); ?>
```